# Staight line Mesh

Tags: plotting

How to see (t,u) junction/nodes with a dot or a small circle connected by straight line in Mesh in 3D, but not as arcs generated by a large number of small steps of t and u.The command should, if possible modify existing ParametricPlot3D without use of Table and ListPlot3D. TIA

```
ParametricPlot3D[ { u Cos[t], u Sin[t],  1.2 u  }, { t, 0, 2 Pi}, {u, 1, 1.5},
  Mesh -> { 25, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: @george2079 Thanks for image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure I understand your question fully.  Does this do what you are looking for?

```
ParametricPlot3D[{u Cos[t], u Sin[t], 1.2 u}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {u, 1, 1.5}, 
   Mesh -> Full, MaxRecursion -> 0, PlotPoints -> {25, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It will not draw arcs, just straight lines between mesh points.  The mesg corresponds to the sampled points precisely (thanks to `Mesh -> Full`), so the mesh density is now controlled by `PlotPoints`.  `MaxRecursion -> 0` prevents automatically refining the mesh.

If you wish to include small dots at the mesh line intersections, I don't believe it will be possible to avoid generating them using `Table`.

Comment: Thanks, Mesh-> Full plots nothing more than chosen sample points.

Comment: @Narasimham There's also `Mesh -> All` which shows the edges of the polygons (always triangles!) making up the object.  `Mesh -> Full` will instead show just the rectangular mesh, not a triangular one.  Both of them just use the sample points.

Comment: +1, `Mesh -> Full` is definitely better. I forget that here is a difference between `Full` and `All`.

Answer (score 5):

Straight mesh lines can be obtaining by specifying corresponding plot points with zero max recursion. Then points can be drawn with post-processing (`/. ... :> ...`)

```
n1 = 10;
n2 = 3;
ParametricPlot3D[{u Cos[t], u Sin[t], 1.2 u}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {u, 1.0, 
   1.5}, Mesh -> {n1, n2}, PlotPoints -> {n1 + 2, n2 + 2}, 
  MaxRecursion -> 0, NormalsFunction -> None, PlotRange -> All, 
  BoundaryStyle -> Darker@Gray, MeshStyle -> Darker@Gray] /. 
 l : Line@p_ :> {Thickness[0.005], l, Sphere[p, 0.05]}
```

[image]

Here I also add `NormalsFunction -> None` to draw flat surface pieces.